# split directory with 10000 files into 2 directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have directory `/logos` which contains approximately  10000 png images. Can you please suggest some script to make two new folders `/logos-1` and `/logos-2` each one with half of the images from initial folder?

Thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be to iterate over the files in the folder, keep and counter and move they files the other directory on each iteration:

```
counter=0
mkdir -p logos-0
mkdir -p logos-1
for file in logos/*
do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue
  echo mv "$file" "logos-$((counter++%2))/"
done
```

Remove the echo if the `mv` commands looks appropriate.

Comment: What is the "-e" inside the brackets doing?

Comment: If the `logos` directory is empty (it's not) then the glob will not expand meaning that `file` will be set to `logos/*` which is something you would avoid trying to work with. Therefore the check for `-e`xistance of the file. Old habits die hard I guess.

Comment: Got it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename`, a.k.a. `Perl rename` and `prename` for that. I assume you don't really want the leading slashes and you aren't really working in the root directory - put them back if you are.

```
rename --dry-run -p -N 01 '$_ = join "", "logos-", $N++%2+1, "/$_"' *.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
'1.png' would be renamed to 'logos-2/1.png'
'10.png' would be renamed to 'logos-1/10.png'
'2.png' would be renamed to 'logos-2/2.png'
'3.png' would be renamed to 'logos-1/3.png'
'4.png' would be renamed to 'logos-2/4.png'
'5.png' would be renamed to 'logos-1/5.png'
'6.png' would be renamed to 'logos-2/6.png'
'7.png' would be renamed to 'logos-1/7.png'
'8.png' would be renamed to 'logos-2/8.png'
'9.png' would be renamed to 'logos-1/9.png'
```

You can remove the `--dry-run` if the output looks good. The `-p` means it will create any necessary directories/paths for you. If you aren't familiar with Perl that means:

*"Set N=1. For each PNG file, make the new name (which we must store in special variable `$_`) equal to the result of joining the word `logos-` with a number alternating between 1 and 2, with a slash followed by whatever it was before (`$_`)."*

---

You may find this alternative way of writing it easier:

```
rename --dry-run -N 01 '$_ = sprintf("logos-%d/$_", $N%2+1)' *.png
```

---

Using this tool confers several benefits:

- you can do dry runs
- you can calculate any replacement you like
- you don't need to create directories
- it will not clobber files if multiple inputs rename to the same output

---

On macOS, use **homebrew** and install with:

```
brew install rename
```